Closest possible zoom level in QField
Our idea is to utilize a GNSS capable handheld android tablet to measure and later on relocalize field trials with QField. For the sake of accuracy we're eyeing devices with RTK-level precision localization capabilities with a maximum "measurement-actual value discrepancy" of +/-2,5cm, which is needed to e.g. relocate subsoilicly installed sampling and probe equipment. For the sake of relocalizing such installations using a relatively high zoom factor (preferably with a length reference scale bar shown within in the map window) seems to be advised. What is the closest zoom QField allows (distance on the scale bar)?

Hi, I quickly tried it out by opening a sample project on QGIS. It seems you can go as low as "1mm" displayed on the scale bar.

You may find that the limiting factor is the basemap you use rather than QField...

The quick answer to your question is: 1mm on the scalebar, based on just trying it out.
If you are concerned about precision, here are a few aspects to keep in mind:

Your equipment, which needs to be RTK-enabled of course ;
Your RTK service, and how close you are to a base ;
The CRS of your project ;
The resolution of your basemap and how well it is georeferenced (this won't directly affect the precision of your measurements, rather the feedback you get on the screen).

Note that you can set up accuracy requirements in QField to always have an indication of how precise your position is.

Agreed on 1, 2, and 4.  The CRS shouldn't matter as long as you use the same setup to capture your features and then to find them later on.

I get a warning from QGIS about precision limits with WGS84. I haven't dug further though.

Thanks your answer is highly appreciated!
